# How to implement a simple while loop using CTE in SQL Server

Tags: loops, while-loop, common-table-expression

I need to implement a stored procedure - where I would be calling another AuditStoredProcedure passing some information.

My current implementation using temp table..

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM @RowIds
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Temp)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @RowId = RowId from #Temp
    --PRINT @RowId
    EXEC @StoredProcName @RowId, @Action 
    DELETE #Temp WHERE RowId = @RowId
END
```

END

Is there a better way to do this using CTE or some other mechanism?.
For my case the temp tables won't have more than 100 rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  What don't you like about this, or what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: General suggestion across the web is not to use while loop and temp tables. Trying to find if there is a Set based approach for achieving the same functionality.